# Excel (.xlsx) to PDF using Java

Tags: java, excel, pdf, xlsx

Is it possible to do .xlsx to PDF conversions using DOCX4J?

- If so, could anyone provide me with some samples please?
- If it isn't possible, what alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use DOCX4j to convert your xlsx to PDF.
You just can use DOCX4j to manipulate Excel xlsx, but not PDF. So you also need a java lib for manipulating PDF, I recommond [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)